# MYSQL - UPDATE record which have same value in column "debit" & date "2019-11-15"

Tags: mysql

I need to update row which having same value in debit column & only row which having create_date ASC basically 2019-11-15

I am having transaction table with following data

```
table name - tbl_transactions

id     client_id     user_id    debit    add_date
1      9991101       1          7.69     2019-11-15
2      9991101       1          7.69     2019-11-30
3      9991101       2          28.9     2019-11-15
4      9991101       2          11.49    2019-11-30
5      9991101       3          17.09     2019-11-15
6      9991101       3          17.09    2019-11-30
```

Now i just want to UPDATE record which have same value in column "debit" & date "2019-11-15"

**which means only id-1 will be get updated.**

```
 id     client_id     user_id    debit    add_date
 1      999110100     1          7.69     2019-11-15
 5      999110100     3          17.09    2019-11-15
```

We can add additional 00 to client_id field, i have tried with below sql but seems its not working

```
 UPDATE tbl_transactions SET client_id=999110100 WHERE id IN ( SELECT * FROM tbl_transactions WHERE client_id=9991101 AND DATE(create_date)='2019-11-15' GROUP BY user_id, debit HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no create_date in your sample data?

Answer (score 0):

for select  you should use

```
select  user_id, debit
from tbl_transactions
INNER JOIN  (
  select distinct user_id
  from tbl_transactions
  where add_date  =  "2019-11-15"
) t2 on t2.user_id = a.user_id
group by  user_id, debit
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

for update you could use

```
update  tbl_transactions a 
INNER JOIN  (
  select  user_id, debit
  from tbl_transactions
  INNER JOIN  (
    select distinct user_id
    from tbl_transactions
    where add_date  =  "2019-11-15"
  ) t2 on t2.user_id = a.user_id
  group by  user_id, debit
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 
) t on t.user_id = a.usre_id 
      and t.debit = a.debit 
set  your_column  =  'your_values'
```

Comment: Group by before where? And you will not get a count = 2 since the dates differ eg for user_id = 1.